# PHP Dynamic Radio Buttons and Submit Button

Tags: php, dynamic, radio-button

I am trying to create a php file that would scan a directory, make a list of dynamic radio buttons and have the user select one and submit it and it shall pass it into another php file that would send it off, but I am having trouble with the submit button. Was wondering if I could get some answers, been looking around the net and haven't been able to find anything.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',true);
//Scan directory (ripped from another site)
$directory = opendir("download");
while($entry = readdir($directory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entry;
}
closedir($directory);
$indexCount = count($dirArray);
sort($dirArray);

//Make the Radio Button list
$RList = "";
for($i=2; $i<count($dirArray); $i++) {
    $value = $dirArray[$i];
    $RList .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Files\" value=".$value." />".$value."<br />";
}
//Submit button
$RButton = '<input type="button" value="Submit" 
onclick="location.href=\'http://localhost/appClient/load.php?file='.$value.'\'">';
echo $RList.$RButton;
#echo $_POST["Files"];

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having? What's not working with your current code? Please be more specific.

Comment: You've way too many radio-buttons and submit buttons!

Comment: @JamWaffles It's not getting the right file when I click submit so there is a problem with the $value not passing the proper data. So how would you go about passing the user selected filename to load.php on the submit click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing `$value` to the onclick event. Since that's outside of the PHP loop, it will end up always being the last `$value`.

To fix this, use javascript to get the selected value from the radio and append that to the onclick redirect.

Better yet, your `load.php` file should just simple check the 'Files' key in your `$_POST` and use that, instead of using GET. That's the point of submitting the radio button, after all.

Comment: Oh I did not notice that. I'm fairly new to all of this, but is there a way to do this through php? and if not would I be able to use javascript within the php programming block? or would i call an outside javascript function from the php?

Comment: To do it through PHP, use a proper form tag with the POST method and it will be available in `$_POST['Files']` when you submit it. No onclick needed.

Comment: Awesome! Finally got it working! Thanks guys for your help!  @ jeremyharris & alvariux

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the `<form>` tag, try to add it because the all buttons and inputs must be within the `<form>`

Does your script is calling the file load.php already or the button just does not work?

Comment: I don't think he needs to use a form tag. He's passing the link in his raw code: `$RButton = '<input type="button" value="Submit" 
onclick="location.href=\'http://localhost/appClient/load.php?file='.$value.'\'">';`

Comment: I don't know how to properly pass $value to load.php.  It will always passes the same file. even when another is selected. and yeah I hardcoded it because im trying to do this in pure php if possible.

Comment: as @jeremyharris sugest, try with the post form `<form method="post" action="load.php">` then you change the button to only `<input type="submit" value="Select file">`, you wiil need to look for the variable `$_POST['Files']`